# Why delphi 10.3 android location sensor doesn't work?

Tags: android, delphi, location, sensors

I'm developing an app for android on Delphi 10.3. I have a location sensor that is active but doesn't work. The program never goes into onlocationchanged event of the sensor location so I cannot get the location of the device. I tried it with location embarcadero sample and doesn't work neither.
Did I forget anything about permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: Just right now I realized that delphi doesn't add authorizations for the app on the device. Once added manually location authorization for app on device - everything's ok

Comment: Martin, maybe you don't know it, but you can answer your own questions. So, just go ahead and write an answer, how to do it, below.